# To get count of products excluding the maximum value of that product in sql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
   1.   Product A   7.5
   2.   Product A   7.3
   3.   Product A   7.4
   4.   Product B   6.2
   5.   Product B   6.5
   6.   Product B   6.01
   7.   Product c   2.4
   8.   Product c   2.0
```

Excluding the max value row of the product A = 7.5  ,then remaining count for that product A will be  2.  So like that i need

```
Product A  2
Product B  2
Product C  1..
```

Comment: What does `7.2.1.1` mean?  This isn't clear at all.  Give your lack of explanation, it would have been helpful to include your attempted query.

Comment: Could you please modify your sample data. It is not clear what the values mean.

Comment: Can there be duplicate values for a product, say 7.2.1.1 twice for product A?

Comment: Is `7.2.1.1` a string in one row or does it represent 4 different rows for one product?

Answer (score 3):

If there would be no duplicates for the maximum value, then you just subtract 1 from COUNT:

```
SELECT product, COUNT(*) - 1 AS counter FROM products GROUP BY product;
```

and this in case there are duplicates and you want them all excluded:

```
SELECT p.product, COUNT(*) AS counter 
FROM products p 
WHERE p.value < (SELECT MAX(value) FROM products WHERE product = p.product) 
GROUP BY p.product;
```

or if you want zeros returned:

```
SELECT 
  p.product, 
  COUNT(*) - (
    SELECT COUNT(*) 
    FROM products 
    WHERE 
      product = p.product 
      AND 
      value = (
        SELECT MAX(value) FROM products WHERE product = p.product
      )
  ) AS counter 
FROM products p 
GROUP BY p.product;
```

Comment: @Joakim Danielson: Looks obvious to me. Counting rows per product and subtracting one (because one value shall not be counted). I came up with the same query.

Answer (score 1):

You might have duplicates with the same maximum value.  If so:

```
select t.product
from t join
     (select product, max(price) as maxprice
      from t
      group by product
     ) tt
     on t.product = tt.product
where t.price < t.maxprice
group by t.product;
```